# Redirect on click to same page on different store

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Shopify project and I've created a pop up that shows, when the page is loaded and asks the user to chose between the US and UK website.

Once the user clicks on one of the options the pop up either closes (UK) or redirects to the US site. This is then stored in a `cookie`, so when they visit the site again, they're redirected again/ the popup doesn't show anymore.

This is the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="storeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="subscription-grid">
          <div class="grid__item">
            <button type="button" class="close" id="subscription-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="store_popup_heading">
              <h2>TEXT</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="store_popup_content">
              <a href="#" class="store-btn" id="uk-store" onClick="checkCookie2();">{{ settings.store_popup_link_text_1 }}</a>
              <a href="#" class="store-btn" id="us-store" onClick="checkCookieUS();">{{ settings.store_popup_link_text_2 }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function checkCookieUS() {
    Cookies.set('storelocation', 'true', {
      expires: 7
    });
    Cookies.set('storelocationUS', 'true', {
      expires: 7
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var delayInMilliseconds = 2000
  var storelocate = Cookies.get('storelocation');
  var storeUS = Cookies.get('storelocationUS');

  if (storelocate) {
    document.getElementById("storeModal").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("storeModal").style.display = "block";
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
  }

  if (storeUS) {
    window.location.href = "https://us.store.com/";
  }
</script>
```

Now this works, but my issue is that if somebody enters from a subpage so `https://store.com/collections` for example, they need to be redirected to the same subpage on the US store so `https://us.store.com/collections`.

I've tried doing this with:

```
if (storeUS) {
  window.location.href = "https://us.store.com/{{current_page}}";
}
```

But then the redirect goes to `https://us.store.com/1` for example.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Whats `current_url`? Maybe just use `${window.location.pathname}` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `pathname` of the current page, and append that to `https://us.store.com/`.

Like this:

```
if (storeUS){
  window.location = "https://us.store.com" + window.location.pathname;
}
```